# Ajax asynchronous response not loading into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

Here is what bothering me. My code is running on `document.ready`. I need the request to be asynchronous, meaning `async: true`

```
for (var i = 0; i < totalGraphs; i++) {
    var kpiId = kpiIds[i];
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: graphUrl,
        data: "kpiId="+kpiId+"&divId="+(i+1),
        async: true, //if false things are working fine
        cache:false,
        success: function(response){
            document.getDocumentById("graph" + (i + 1)).innerHTML("hello");
        },
        error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        }
    });
}
```

This request does not put hello in my graphX divs, but whenever i put `async: false` things are working fine. I really need the request to be asynchronous.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `does not put hello in my graphX divs` or puts in the last div only?

Comment: What is the value of `totalGraphs`? I imagine if you're sending a lot of requests very quickly the server may be blocking any response to you.

Comment: `data` should be an object, not a string.

Comment: @RtotalGraphs are not very much just in bw 4-6

Comment: @Archer not true, you can send data as a string.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for the tip.  I just read up about that - I didn't know it converted it to a string anyway.

Comment: `jQuey.ajax()` calls are non blocking and when you make a quick succession of aynchroneous calls, C1, C2, C3,... it is not guaranteed that their responses will arrive in the same order R1, R2, R3... So you either need to send some ID in the response (as Chris  Dixon said) or a closure solution proposed by Archer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this...

```
for (var i = 0; i < totalGraphs; i++){
    (function ajaxCall(index) {
        var kpiId = kpiIds[index];
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: graphUrl,
            data: {
                kpiId : kpiId,
                divId : index + 1
            },
            async: true, //if false things are working fine
            cache: false,
            success: function(response) {
                document.getDocumentById("graph" + (index + 1)).innerHTML("hello");
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown) {}
        });
    })(i);
}
```

I've wrapped the ajax call in an anonymous function so that the value of `i` will never change, relative to the ajax call.

Comment: hey its working but why its working?? i'm gonna accept this as answer

Comment: I've made a slight change to it that will help explain better (I find this concept difficult to put into words).  Inside the loop I created a function that is called immediately, passing in `i` as the parameter `index`.  That parameter is then used within that function in place of `i`.  Since the value of `index` is a local variable, it will never change.  **[This looks like a good explanation of anonymous functions](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/)** - have a read of that and see if it helps explain :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing the `i` count is getting mixed up in your loop when success is returned. `success` will return after the loop has run through and thus this will give an unexpected result.

Can you return the `i` value that went sent in `data` in your `response` then use this in your `getDocumentById` method? I'm guessing this would fix your issue.

New code to try:

```
for(var i=0;i<totalGraphs;i++){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: graphUrl,
        data: { kpiId: kpiIds[i], divId: (i+1) },
        async: true, //if false things are working fine
        cache:false,
        success: function(response){
            document.getDocumentById("graph" + response.count).innerHTML("hello");
        },
        error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are running an ajax call inside a loop. This will be okay if you've turned off the async. But since you've turned on the async, the loop doesn't wait for the ajax to finish its work.

The best thing to do would be to get the values to a global variable using the inner loop ajax and then use the variable to draw the graph later.